# Android calendar monthview example

Tags: android, calendar, android-calendar

I am looking for **android month view library** or example which is similar to android default calendar with vertical scrolling.

I got few libraries but they don't have any similarities to android default calendar nor have vertical scrolling.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker check this

Comment: @AndroidDeveloper,I am not looking for date picker kind of thing.I want month view calendar.

Comment: https://github.com/developersuru/android-month-year-picker